# assembly x86 nasm outputting float values

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, assembly, nasm, x86-64

I"m working on a project and I need to output floating point values using `printf` from C.

I'm able to print out the values right now, but I'm not really sure how the printing is taking place.

For printing int values, I just push the data type and location and it prints fine.

But for float its a whole different story.

Here is code for printing floats

```
mov qword rdi, float_format                          
push qword 0                                         
push r14                                            
movsd xmm0, [rsp]                                    
mov qword rax, 1                                     
call printf                                          
pop rax                                               
pop rax
```

That will effectly print out a value that was inputed from the keyboard. However, when I manipulate the number with float commands like `fadd` or `fdiv`, in order to print out, prior to calling the print float function I have to `mov 1, rax`

Ideas? To make it simpler? Or explanation as to why I"m using xmm0?

Comment: What are the C compiler and OS? Correct `printf()` invocation depends on those.

Comment: the OS is Ubuntu 11.xx and the compiler i'm using is NASM/gcc

Comment: Write similar program in C, compile with key -S and look at the produces assembly text.

Comment: writing the program in C and reverse engineering it, I hear writes a lot of junk assembly code. rather not have to go that route

Comment: @user1050632:  It is not that bad.  There is some stuff you might not understand, but focus on the instructions just before (and the few after) the `call _printf` to see what is needed.  You should be able to copy/paste 90% of what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the calling conventions in use. Linux on AMD64 uses the [System V AMD64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi-0.98.pdf). From that document we learn that:

- integer arguments are passed in rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8 and r9
- floats are passed in xmm0 to xmm7
- for varargs functions the number of SSE registers used is put in rax

So for the call

```
printf (format, float_value)
```

you have rdi=format, xmm0=float_value and rax=1.

Comment: Note that this is a tad different on Windows x64. They have a custom AMD64 ABI.

Comment: this make sense, however when i try to replicate this in my assemlby ,it doesn't work

Comment: is there any other way of printing a float, while not using printf?